# How to look at the top 30 lines (or head) of all files inside a directory?

Tags: linux

If I have 30+ files in a directory `/a.cpp` `/b.cpp` `/c.cpp` `...`

What's the fastest way to export the head (top n lines) of all files into one single document?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html):

```
head -n 10 *.cpp > all_headers.txt
```

The above command exports the first 10 lines of all cpp files in a folder into `all_headers.txt`.

According to [Aereaux's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850722/how-to-look-at-the-top-30-lines-or-head-of-all-files-inside-a-directory/30850774?noredirect=1#comment49747837_30850774) you should also use the `-q` option of `head` since otherwise `head` would print the file name before the n lines. It should be:

```
head -qn 10 *.cpp > all_headers.txt
```

Another thing. Depending on the number of files, using globbing can lead to a situation where the argument list for `head` gets too long. For a stable solution which can work with any amount of files, I would use `find`:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name '*.cpp' -exec head -qn 10 {} +
```

Comment: Beware though, as this will leave a header between each file.  If you want to avoid that, use the -q option.

Comment: -nq will not work because the 10 needs to be right after the n.  Try -qn.

Comment: Sure, missed that! I'm in a hurry ... :)

Answer (score 3):

`head -qn <number of lines> <dir>/* > <document>`